# Changing large amount of code with Regex

Tags: c++, regex, eclipse

I have a function writtin in c++ :

```
void createForm(Form*& form,string name,int code)
```

And in my project, there are hundreds of call to this function :

```
createForm(foo,"a",0x2020);
```

## Now I wanna change this statement to :

```
createForm(foo,0x2020);//"a"
```

That is to say , second parameter of this function become comment. I don't really need this parameter at all.

If anyone could offer me a magic regex to make this change **at one shot?** **Thanks in advance.**

**BTW:** I'm using eclipse.

Comment: Are you on linux? Or do you have cygwin installed? You can do this with find + sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the "File Search" Dialog which can be found under "Search" -> "File..." in eclipse's menu. Turn regex mode on (checkbox).

Pattern:

```
createForm\((\w+),(".*?"),(\w+)\);
```

Replacement:

```
createForm($1,$3);//$2
```

It is quite simple, we capture the three arguments in capturing groups (in parenthesis) and refer to these capturing groups with the `$x` patterns.

This pattern assumes that the second parameter is always a string literal without quoted `"`s and the other two parameters are either identifiers or numbers. If this is not the case let me know.

Comment: how to turn on regex mode?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: See the top of my answer. It is a checkbox in the file search dialog.

Comment: `[^"]` instead of `.` for the second parameter ?

Comment: @Geoffroy: That would be no difference. I use the reluctant quantifier `*?` (forgot the `*` at first) which does the same.

Comment: Wow ! It's the real magic ! It worked for me! Thank you so much !

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Hit the `Replace...` button, then you can enter it.

Comment: yep, now only i got that. +1 for your info.